# extends Vueはtypescriptの機能ですか？

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

Vue.jsでextends Vueというのをよく使うのですが
先日にtypescriptの機能だと教わりました

javascriptにextendsがあるので
javascriptの機能だと思っていたのですが
これは本当にtypescriptの機能なのでしょうか？

簡単な質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

まずTypeScriptはaltJSと呼ばれるものの一種で、実行時にJavaScriptに変換されるスクリプトです。
JavaScriptだとどこでも動いて便利ですが、静的型付けを使ってしっかり作りたいとか、ミスを減らしたいなどの理由で開発がさかんです。

extends VueはVue.extend()のこととして解釈しますが(もし違ったらご指摘ください)、これはVueコンポーネントを継承して新規にコンポーネントを作成する命令でTypeScriptと親和性が高いとされています。もちろんJavaScriptからも利用できます。

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend

最後に、Vue.extend()がjavascriptの機能かtypescriptの機能かという話ですが、これはVue.jsの機能じゃないでしょうか。Vue.js自体はjavascriptで書かれてるようですね。

### 追記

extends構文に関することとのことでしたので追記します。extends構文はJavaScriptにはES6(2015)から実装された比較的新しいものです。TypeScriptで作成したスクリプトではextendsの構文を利用してそれ以前のJavaScriptの環境でも動作させることもできます。講師の方がここで説明されたいのは、そのことではないかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。vue.jsにあまり詳しくないのですが、class Hoge extends Vueといった記法がTypeScriptで用意されたものかあるいはJSのextends構文を使てVueクラスを継承しているのかが知りたいと思いました。Vue.extend()と同様にVuejsの機能という理解でよろしｋいでしょうか?

Comment: あ、はいそれでしたらneketsuuuさんの回答が参考になると思います。それは単なる継承を示す構文です。あなたがTypeScript上で記述されているのなら、それはTypeScriptの機能といえますね。extendsキーワードがJSに追加されたのが最近なため、TypeScriptの機能ですと講師の方は説明されているのかもしれません。

Comment: 回答していただきありがとうございました！

Comment: ところで、参考に貼られているVueのドキュメントがかなり古いバージョンのもののようです。。。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます

Comment: 静的片付け→静的型付け
でした。編集しようとしたら文字数が少なすぎて受け付けてくれませんでした。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。訂正しました

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript の構文は JavaScript の構文を拡張する形で作られています。つまり JavaScript で使える構文は TypeScript でも使えます（あくまで構文の話であって、コンパイルすると型エラーが出ることはあるかもしれませんが）。

つまり、class を extends する構文は [JavaScript で使えます](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)が、TypeScript でも使えます。どちらでも使える構文です。

Comment: TypeScriptはＪＳのスーパーセットと聞いたことがあり納得がしました。回答していただきありがとうございました！